# I am getting certificate hostname verification failed errror while login to spark openfire

Tags: openfire

Hello i have istalled to openfire into my computer.I am trying to login to spark using username password and ip address as domain but i am getting I am getting certificate hostname verification failed errror.I found that that they are asking to change server i tried that option as well no result.

Answer (score 0):

When we install Openfire server, it generates self-signed certificates for SSL connections. Now if you are in development phase, you don't need to worry about this error. However, once you go into production, you might consider placing proper HTTPS certificates against your domain.

Certificate directory: OPENFIRE_HOME/resources/security/